# Java - I do not have Swing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, wizard

Ok so I know that I have the swing library because I can add JFrames programmatically. However, I cannot add a JFrame in Eclipse with New > Other > Swing etc. as I do not have the Swing folder amongst my other Wizards.

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/957c304fe13fb5741c122719faaf8856.png?1358020174))</sub>

How do I add the Swing Wizard?

Sorry if this is a really idiotic question but I do not understand.

Comment: It's part of core Java. If you have Java, you have Swing. Voting to close since this really is a one-off question answerable through comments, although I didn't down-vote this.

Comment: Ah shoot, you're not looking for ***Swing***, you're looking for a Swing Window builder. Please improve your question. You don't need a code builder but can and should create Swing code by hand. again, the library is part of core Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's not such wizard for swing. There's also no built-in option to create those with a GUIBuilder or something like that. But there are plugins to do that.
It seems like you installed Google's WindowBuilder which has this functionality. Maybe you should read in the FAQ's how to use it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/?hl=de) may be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Search the Eclipse Marketplace for a Swing plugin that might add what you need.